# How does one prove $R \otimes_R A $ is isomorphic to $A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. I would like to prove that $R \otimes_R A $ is isomorphic to $A$, where $A$ is a $R$-algebra.

How can I prove this?

Comment: Set up mutually inverse homomorphisms between the two rings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: try

$$f:R\otimes_RA\to A\;,\;\;f(r\otimes a):=ra$$

$$g:A\to R\otimes_RA\;,\;\;g(a):=1\otimes a$$